# Save RAM by making Activities transparent?

Tags: android, android-activity, transparent, ram

I have several Activities on top of each other. Each of the Activities uses exactly the same background image.

What is the most RAM-efficient way to implement this?

Can I gain something by making all activities transparent, so that the background image of the bottom activity "shines through" to all other activities?

Comment: Why don't you use a single Activity containing Fragments?

Comment: The transparency effect while it is very awesome it also adds significant overhead to the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Just have all of your activities reference the same background image object if you really want to save memory (for example, by storing the image in some sort of static cache... just make sure the memory isn't leaked when the user leaves the application). Making the activities transparent in order to achieve this effect seems very messy to me.

Answer (score 1):

Making your `Activity` transparent actually consumes *more* resources, as now you have at least two visible windows. This is almost certainly premature optimization -- just set your image as the `windowBackground` on your `Activity`'s theme. Android handles caching of `Drawable` resources automatically, so unless you're having a particular issue with memory usage, don't overthink this.